# Swift 4: didSet @IBOutlet calls viewDidLayoutSubviews, but not with addSubview()

Tags: ios, swift, layoutsubviews, viewdidlayoutsubviews

When `selectCard` is called, by commenting out various parts of the code I've discovered that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is only called when `score` is updated in `checkIfCardsMatch` function. The score is only updated if we have `matchedCards`. Why is this happening?

I would like to have `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called every time `selectCard` is called. I noticed if I add `CardTable.addSubview(grid)` to my `resetTable` function than `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time `selectCard` is called EXECPT when score is changed.

What is going on here and how can I make sure `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called on each card selection?

```
// Score
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }
    private var score = 0 {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }

    func selectCard(card: Card) {
        // must deal more cards if we have a match first
        if !matched.isEmpty && !game.cards.isEmpty {
            print("must deal more cards if we have a match first")
            resetTable()
            return
        }

        // deal no longer possible
        if !matched.isEmpty && game.cards.isEmpty {
            print("deal no longer possible")
            clearAndDeal()
        }

        // reset any mismatched card styles
        if !misMatched.isEmpty {
            print("reset any mismatched card styles")
            resetMisMatchedStyle()
        }

        // select or deselect card
        game.select(card: card)
        if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
            visibleCards[idx].state = .selected
        }

        // check for match
        checkIfCardsMatch()
        // resetTable
        resetTable()
    }

    private func resetTable(){
        grid = CardTableView(frame: CardTable.bounds, cardsInPlay: visibleCards)
        grid.delegate = self
    }

    private func checkIfCardsMatch(){
        if let matchedCards = game.matchedCards() {
            print("MATCHED!", matchedCards)
            matched = matchedCards
            game.clearSelectedCards()
            score += 3
            // set visible cards to matched
            for card in matched {
                if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                    visibleCards[idx].state = .matched
                }
            }
        }else {
            if game.selectedCards.count == 3 {
                print("no match")
                misMatched = game.selectedCards
                game.clearSelectedCards()
                score -= 5
                for card in misMatched {
                    if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                        visibleCards[idx].state = .misMatched
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

### }

The whole file:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Set
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CardTableViewDelegate {
    func delegateCardTap(card: Card){
        print("called in view controller")
        selectCard(card: card)
    }
    // Game
    private var game = SetGame()
    private lazy var grid = CardTableView(frame: CardTable.bounds, cardsInPlay: visibleCards)
    // table to place all cards
    @IBOutlet weak var CardTable: UIView! {
        didSet {
            // set up buttons with 12 cards
            initalDeal()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func newGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
        score = 0
        game = SetGame()
        visibleCards.removeAll()
        matched.removeAll()
        misMatched.removeAll()
        dealMoreButton.isEnabled = true
        dealMoreButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.231372549, green: 0.6, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        initalDeal()
        grid.cards = visibleCards
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        grid.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // reset frame when device rotates
        grid.frame = CardTable.bounds

        // add cards to the card table
        CardTable.addSubview(grid)
    }
    // Cards
    private var visibleCards = [Card]()

    // Score
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }
    private var score = 0 {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }

    // Deal
    @IBOutlet weak var dealMoreButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func deal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // have a match and cards available to deal
        if !matched.isEmpty && !game.cards.isEmpty {
            //TODO: fix this for new UI
            clearAndDeal()
        } else {
            dealThreeMore()
        }
        // disable if we run out of cards
        if game.cards.isEmpty {
            disable(button: sender)
        }
        grid.cards = visibleCards
    }
    private func dealThreeMore(){
        if visibleCards.count < game.cardTotal {
            for _ in 0..<3 {
                if let card = game.drawCard() {
                    // add more visible cards
                    visibleCards.append(card)
                } else {
                    print("ran out of cards in the deck!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func disable(button sender: UIButton){
        sender.isEnabled = false
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    }
    private func clearAndDeal(){
        print("in clearAndDeal")
        //TODO: rewrite me
        for card in matched {
            if let index = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                // remove matched styles
                // draw new card
                if let newCard = game.drawCard() {
                    // swap with old card
                    replace(old: index, with: newCard)
                } else {
                    // ran out of cards in the deck!
                    hideButton(by: index)
                }
            }
        }
        matched.removeAll()
    }

    private var allCardsMatched: Bool {
        let cards = visibleCards.filter({card in
            //            if let index = visibleCards.index(of: card){
            ////                return cardButtons[index].isEnabled
            //            }
            return false
        })
        return cards.count == 3
    }
    private var misMatched = [Card]()
    private var matched = [Card]()

    func selectCard(card: Card) {
        // must deal more cards if we have a match first
        if !matched.isEmpty && !game.cards.isEmpty {
            print("must deal more cards if we have a match first")
            resetTable()
            return
        }

        // deal no longer possible
        if !matched.isEmpty && game.cards.isEmpty {
            print("deal no longer possible")
            clearAndDeal()
        }

        // reset any mismatched card styles
        if !misMatched.isEmpty {
            print("reset any mismatched card styles")
            resetMisMatchedStyle()
        }

        // select or deselect card
        game.select(card: card)
        if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
            visibleCards[idx].state = .selected
        }

        // check for match
        checkIfCardsMatch()
        // resetTable
        resetTable()
    }

    private func resetTable(){
        grid = CardTableView(frame: CardTable.bounds, cardsInPlay: visibleCards)
        grid.delegate = self
    }

    private func checkIfCardsMatch(){
        if let matchedCards = game.matchedCards() {
            print("MATCHED!", matchedCards)
            matched = matchedCards
            game.clearSelectedCards()
            score += 3
            // set visible cards to matched
            for card in matched {
                if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                    visibleCards[idx].state = .matched
                }
            }
        }else {
            if game.selectedCards.count == 3 {
                print("no match")
                misMatched = game.selectedCards
                game.clearSelectedCards()
                score -= 5
                for card in misMatched {
                    if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                        visibleCards[idx].state = .misMatched
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func initalDeal(){
        for _ in 0..<12 {
            if let card = game.drawCard() {
                visibleCards.append(card)
            }
        }
    }

    private func removeStyleFrom(button: UIButton){
        button.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    private func resetMisMatchedStyle(){
        for card in misMatched {
            if let idx = visibleCards.index(of: card){
                visibleCards[idx].state = nil
            }
        }
        misMatched.removeAll()
    }

    private func replace(old index: Int, with newCard: Card){
        visibleCards[index] = newCard
        //        style(a: cardButtons[index], by: newCard)
    }

    private func hideButton(by index: Int){
        //        let button = cardButtons[index]
        //        button.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string:""), for: .normal)
        //        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        //        button.isEnabled = false
    }

    private func styleTouched(button: UIButton, by card: Card) {
        if game.selectedCards.contains(card) {
            button.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9848672538, green: 0.75109528, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        }else {
            removeStyleFrom(button: button)
        }
    }
}
```